# Passing parameter to bootstrap modal button

Tags: html, jsp, twitter-bootstrap, servlets

I have a delete link , for that I am using bootstrap modal window . Here window appearing fine When I click yes button of window the record should be delete. So I have to call servlet in yes button along with a parameter `Id` here I am able to call servlet but parameter is not passing. How can I pass parameter to yes button of modal window. Here is code for it.

The bootstrap modal where I am calling,

```
<td><a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/pages/teacher_details/teacher_info.jsp?teacherId=${teacher.getTeacherId()}">Edit</a>
</td>
<td> <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicModal">Delete</a>
</td>
```

in the same jsp page the markup of modal is,

```
<div class="modal fade" id="basicModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Delete Teacher Record</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h3>Are you sure?</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
        <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button> -->
        <a  href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/controller/TeacherManagementController?flowName=DELETE_TEACHER_INFO&teacherId=${teacherId.getTeacherId()}"
                    class="btn btn-primary">Yes</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem I am facing is the modal is appearing but record is not delete because of not able to pass the teacherId. Please any one help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

I am using like this call function and assign value to hidden fields

Html:

```
    <div id="add_button" >
    <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal_new" onClick="pop_up('<?php echo      $section_value['subject_name']; ?>','<?php echo $section_value['section_id']; ?>')">Add    Subjects</a>
    </div>





    <script>
    function pop_up(name,id){
    var standard = document.getElementById("standard");
    var standard_id = document.getElementById("standard_id");
    var standard_id_new = document.getElementById("standard_id_new");

    standard.value = name;
    standard_id.value = id;
    standard_id_new.value = id;
    }
    </script>



 <div id="myModal_new" class="modal hide fade">
     <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h3>Create Sections</h3>
        </div><br><br>
        <div id="errorContainers">
                <p>Please correct the errors and try again:</p>
                <ul />
            </div>
        <div class="modal-body" style="margin-left: 17%;">
          <!-- Modal Form Starts Here -->
                <form name="modalForm" id="formss" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="standard" id="standard">
                    <input type="hidden" name="standard_id" id="standard_id">
                        <input type="hidden" name="standard_id_new" id="standard_id_new">
                        <fieldset>  
                          <div class="division_center"><div class="division_left"><label class="form-signin-signup"  for="input1">Sections </label>  </div>
                            <div class="division_right">
                            &nbsp;<input type="text"  name="standard_new" id="standard_new"> </div></div>                               
                           </fieldset> 

            <!-- Modal Form Ends Here -->
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <a class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" >Close</a>
          <input type="submit" name="newsubmit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" value="Create">
        </div>
        </form>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: k . . in my case how can I set hidden field value